# Ruby Regular Expression not to match if bracket is escaped

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to extract string surrounded by curly bracket by using regular expression in ruby.
I create the following regular expression:

```
/\A({[^(})]*})/i
```

I add `^(})` to regular expression because I want the shortest match.
It means:

```
target string: {aaa}XXX{aaa}

expected: {aaa}

when I remove `^(})` (the regular expression is `/\A({*})/i`)
I will obtain: `{aaa}XXX{aaa}`
```

It works very well in many cases.

What I want to do is avoid matching when I escape by using backslash.

```
target string: "{aaa\}}"

expected match: {aaa\}}
```

Actual matching result is `{aaa\}`.
How should I change my regular expression to obtain the expected match?

Comment: Escaping the right brace has no effect: `"{aaa\}}" == "{aaa}}" #=> true`. With single parentheses `'\'` in `'{aaa\}}'` is a backslash: `'{aaa\}}'[4] #=> "\\"`.

Comment: Thanks. How about `"{aaa\\}}"`?

Comment: `"\\"` is a single backslash but in the question you referred to "escaping". Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by "I want the shortest match". Perhaps give some more examples, showing the desired match for each (as you have done for the example you gave).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks! Sorry for bad explanation. I add an example for shortest match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind to find a closing parenthesis that is not escaped.

```
{.*?(?<!\\)}
```

Here it is commented

```
{ # opening parenthesis
.* # followed by anything
? # match as little as possible. This should cover your shortest match clause.
(?<!\\)} # followed by a closing parenthesis that is not preceded by a backslash.
```

Do note though, that this will cover escaping, but will not cover double escaping. `"\\}"` and `"\\\\}"`are still considered escaped and will not be matched.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```rb
/\A\{[^\\{}]*(?:\\.[^\\{}]*)*}/m
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/zpJZdXhhU1acSk).

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `\{` - a `{` char
- `[^\\{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `\`, `{` and `}`
- `(?:\\.[^\\{}]*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\\.` - any escaped char
  - `[^\\{}]*` - zero or more chars other than `\`, `{` and `}`
- `}`  - a `}` char.

Note that `m` flag is used to make `.` match any chars including line break chars.